# Can I verify a file with GPG without downloading the key

Tags: gpg, iso, key-authentication, bootable, signature

To verify an `.iso` written on `/dev/sdb` with the signature `my_signature.sig` in `gpg`, I use

```
dd if=/dev/sdb | gpg --keyid-format 0xlong --verify my_signature.sig -
```

Is there a way to execute this command without even downloading the signature `my_signature.sig`?

Comment: Sure: you can arrange to meet the author of the file and get the signature on an USB stick. :)

Comment: A "fille" probably not, a "file" however, my work... (i.e. "fille" means "girl" in French.)

Comment: Are you looking for something like `curl -sL URL | gpg --keyid-format 0xlong --verify <(curl -sL URL.sig)`? That is, downloading both the file and its signature, without storing them?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.  If you don't have the signature file `my_signature.sig` (here known as a "detached signature"), how are you supposed to verify that the content you retrieved via curl is correctly signed?

Additionally, you need to have the public key of the signer stored in your keyring, otherwise you will be unable to verify the signature.

Answer (score 1):

No, GPG needs the <del>signature to calculate if it's correct, so you have to download it, if you do not have it already imported in your keyring.</del>
The key has to be downloaded to verify the signature if not already in keyring. If the signature does not come in the text you receive with curl you nevertheless will need to download it, at least if you do not know who signed the URL content.

Comment: You are mixing up *signatures* and *public keys*. A signature has no place in a keyring.

Comment: You are right, I mixed it up. The key has to be downloaded to verify the signature if not already in keyring. If the signature does not come in the text you receive with curl you nevertheless will need to download it, at least if you do not know who signed the URL content.

Answer (score 0):

If the signature is at the url `URL`,

```
dd if=/dev/sdb | gpg --keyid-format 0xlong --verify <(curl -sL URL.sig)
```

The key that is added with `gpg --import` should however have been downloaded unless it is a SHS key for instance.